# How to mound a directory on MacOS host to Windows guest in VMware?

Tags: windows, windows-10, macos, vmware, vmware-fusion

I have a Windows 10 guest on VMware Fusion on MacOS. I want to share a directory on the host to the guest. Could anybody let me know how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Did you install the VMware Tools in the Windows Guest?  Going the other way around with Tools installed in Linux guests, I just used smb://192.168.x.y/folder   So that is map by IP address and that works fine (several Linux)  .   MAC should be similar.

Comment: No. The host is MacOS. The guest is Windows.

Comment: True. If guest extensions are installed, you should be able to use SMB followed by the drive mapping on the MAC. You may need a MAC terminal for this.  Otherwise, you may need to install Samba and use that.

Comment: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1004055